# Call method when variable is changed

Tags: python

I have a variable which is a list, which contains a large number of people in it. something like:

```
'citizens = ['John', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'Jonas']`
#imagine hundreds of names
```

I would like to 'link' a variable, `population` to the length of this list, so that whenever the list is modified, the `population` variable will update. Up until now, I have been simply calling a function like so:

```
def update_population()
    global population
    population = len(citizens)
```

but is seems like there would be a more elegant solution, so this can be automatically triggered without my explicitly calling it.

Comment: You want a class that has a `citizens` field and a `population` method decorated with `@property`.

Answer (score 4):

If this is in a class somewhere, then you could make a it a property, e.g.

```
@property
def population(self):
    return len(self.citizens)
```